# Find $g(x)$ in $(x+y)\text{d}x + g(x)\text{d}y = 0$ such that the integrating factor is $x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have rearranged the equation so it takes the form of a linear first-order differential equation.

$$ (x+y) + g(x)\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = 0$$
$$ \frac{x}{g(x)} + \frac{y}{g(x)} + \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = 0$$
$$ \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + \frac{y}{g(x)} = - \frac{x}{g(x)} $$

I have obtained the following:

$$ e^{\int \frac{1}{g(x)}\text{d}x} = x $$
$$ \int \frac{1}{g(x)}\text{d}x = \text{ln}(x) $$
$$ \frac{1}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$ g(x) = x $$

However the book gives the answer:

$$ g(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{k}{x} , k \in \mathbb{R}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x+y)dx+g(x)dy$ is supposed to be not a total differential since it is said that an integrating factor $=x$ is necessary.

With the integrating factor, the total differential is $\quad x(x+y)dx+xg(x)dy$.

This implies :
$$\frac{\partial x(x+y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial xg(x)}{\partial x}$$
$\frac{\partial x(x+y)}{\partial y}=x$

$\frac{\partial xg(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{d(xg(x))}{dx}$

$$x=\frac{d(xg(x))}{dx}$$
After integration :
$$\frac12 x^2+c=xg(x)$$
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{c}{x}$$
$$ $$

IN ADDITION : Comment about your method.

If $x$ is an integrating factor for the original ODE : 
$$x+y+g(x)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$xg(x)$ is an integrating factor for the modified ODE :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{g(x)}+\frac{x}{g(x)}=0$$
because for both the related exact ODE is :
$$x\left(x+y+g(x)\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=xg(x)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{g(x)}+\frac{x}{g(x)}\right)=0$$
Thus $e^{\int \frac{dx}{g(x)}}=x$ is not correct.
$$e^{\int \frac{dx}{g(x)}}=xg(x)$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{g(x)}=\ln(x)+\ln(g(x))$$
$$\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$
$$g'(x)+\frac{g(x)}{x}=1$$
This is a linear first order ODE easy to solve. The solution is :
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{c}{x}$$

Comment: What is a total differential? Could you be more specific about why I couldn't obtain the expected result?

Comment: One cannot tackle this kind of problem without being familiar with partial differential and total differential. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables . The definition of "total differential" is given in this page.

Comment: For me going from $ \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + \frac{y}{g(x)} = - \frac{x}{g(x)} $ to $ e^{\int \frac{1}{g(x)}\text{d}x} = x $ is non-sens. May be if you edit the intermediate steps, one could see where is the hitch.

Comment: Equivalently, see also "Exact differential" : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactDifferential.html . I don't know what is the most common use.

Comment: I have seen these concepts (sorry, its the language barrier). I have used the formula for solving linear first-order differential equations, where you obtain a integrating factor by doing $e^{\int p(x) \text{d}x}$, being $p(x)$ the function of x that accompanies the y-term.

Comment: The ready made recipe gives the integrating factor $e^{\int \frac{dx}{g(x)}}$ . OK. But how do you get that it's $=x$ ? I was asking for the intermediate steps for your supposed equality. $e^{\int \frac{dx}{g(x}}=x$.

Comment: It is given that the integrating factor is $x$.

Comment: In the original wording of the problem  $x$ is the integrating factor of what equation ? Is it the integrating factor of $(x+y)dx+g(x)dy=0$ or is it the integrating factor of $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + \frac{y}{g(x)} = - \frac{x}{g(x)} $. Don't think that they have the same integrating factor. If $x$ is the integrating factor of the first equation, then the integrating factor of the second equation is not $x$: it is $e^{\int \frac{dx}{g(x)}}\neq x$. The mistake is here. You divide the  original ODE not by a constant, but by a function  $g(x)$ so, you change the integrating factor.

Comment: See the comment about your method, posted in addition to my first answer.

Comment: thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the book was referring to integration factor in the context of exact differential equations. Meaning - equations that can be viewed as a gradient of a scalar field (also called a potential). You can show that a differential equation of the form $f(x,y)dx+h(x,y)dy=0$ is exact if and only if it satisfies:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$

If an equation is not exact, we can usually make it exact by finding an integration factor - some function $\mu(x,y)$ that if we multiply the equation by it, we get an exact equation. After multiplying your equation by $\mu=x$ we get the equation:

$(x^2+xy)dx+xg(x)dy=0$

Since we want the equation to be exact, we shall demand:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\Rightarrow x=g(x)+xg'(x)$

This is another differential equation, which we can solve for $g(x)$. Conveniently enough, it is in fact an exact equation! We can express it as:

$(g-x)dx+xdg=0$

We can check and see that it is indeed exact:

$1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=1$

Now, all we need is to find our potential - some scalar field $F(x,g)$ such that:

$f= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}, h=\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}$.

And indeed, we can easily find that $F(x,g)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2+gx-k=0$ satisfies our condition. By rearranging we get the answer:

$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{k}{x}$

Comment: Why couldn't I transform the differential equation in a linear first-order form?

Comment: You could, but that's not the type of integration factor the question was referring to. The term has several different meanings (which refer to different types of differential equations), and it seems that the question was referring to the type associated with exact equations (that's probably why the equation was given in its original form, and not in the form you rearranged it into). Your way wasn't wrong - it's just not what the author was asking about :)